# How to find amount exclusive of tax from an amount inclusive of tax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

How to find amount exclusive of tax from an amount inclusive of tax?
Currently I'm using this query and getting the desired result. 
I am searching for a simple query.

My current query:

```
select @amountExclusiveOfTax=
    (@amountInclusiveOfTax) - 
    ((@amountInclusiveOfTax) - (((@amountInclusiveOfTax)/@taxPercent+100) * 100))
```

Is there any easier way?

Comment: You can't get any simpler than the formula that gives you the answer :P

Comment: Not really.  Note that there is a real danger here of trying to simplify the formula by dividing all terms by @amountInclusiveOfTax and multiplying at the end because putting money data types in the denominator is just asking for trouble with your pennies later.

Comment: Note: All fields are numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was taught in day one of my business math class:

```
SELECT @amountExclusiveOfTax = @amountInclusiveOfTax / (1 + @taxPercetange / 100)
```

This assume your `@taxPercentage` is stored in percentage form. For example, if the tax is 15%, then `@taxPercentage = 15`. Another popular form is the decimal form, where it's stored as 0.15.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you.